# Android ListAdapter Repaint

Tags: android, listview

i have the following problem. I fill a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter with data from a BD. However, in background, i'm updating those datas from the info provided by an API, so the idea is when the update finish, the adapter shows the updated data instead its "**old version**".

The problem is that when i do that, i notice a lag while the adapter is updating itself. Is the any efficient solution to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call notifyDataSetChanged() on your ListAdapter to cause it to update to the current data immediately.  Note that you should do this from the main UI thread, using a Handler or Activity.runOnUIThread()